# Codeigniter error : Fatal error: Cannot use object of type CI_DB_mysql_result as array

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to implement a php codeigniter model for tree and every time I run my controller, I am getting the following error :

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type CI_DB_mysql_result as array in
>   C:\AppServ\www\tree\application\models\Btree.php on line 50

I tried to fix this syntax in line

```
$currentID = $row['id'];
```

however, still getting the same error message.

My model function is:

```
public function fetchTree($parentArray, $parentID = null)
{
    // Create the query
    if ($parentID == null)
        $parentID = -1;

    $sql = "SELECT `id` FROM `{$this->tblName}` WHERE `id`= ". intval($parentID);

    // Execute the query and go through the results.
    $result = $this->db->query($sql);
    if ($result)
    {
        while ($row = $result)
        {
            // Create a child array for the current ID
            $currentID = $row['id'];
            $parentArray[$currentID] = array();

            // Print all children of the current ID
            $this->fetchTree($parentArray[$currentID], $currentID);
        }
        $result->close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is with this line:

```
while($row = $result)
```

You're setting `$row` to the entire query object. You want to loop through the *results* of the query.

Try this instead:

```
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
foreach($query->result_array() AS $row) {
    $currentID = $row['id'];
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

just the simpler solution is to have direct conversion to arrays:

```
$result = $this->db->query($sql)->result_array();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    public function fetchTree($parentArray, $parentID = null)
{

     // Create the query
        if ($parentID == null)
            $parentID = -1;

    $sql = "SELECT `id` FROM `{$this->tblName}` WHERE `id`= ". intval($parentID);

    // Execute the query and go through the results.
    $result = $this->db->query($sql);
    if ($result)
    {
        while ($row = $result)
        {
            // Create a child array for the current ID
            $currentID = $row['id'];
            $parentArray[$currentID] = array();

            // Print all children of the current ID
            $this->fetchTree($parentArray[$currentID], $currentID);
        }
        $result->close();
    }
}
```