# Fatal error: Cannot use object of type CI_DB_mysql_result as array

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have read [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20022662/codeigniter-error-fatal-error-cannot-use-object-of-type-ci-db-mysql-result-as), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29598028/codeigniter-fatal-error-cannot-use-object-of-type-ci-db-mysql-result-as-array) and several other threads prior to post this issue but none of them solved my problem. I am totally new with PHP and got stuck in attempting to learn MVC with codeigniter. The function which causing error is

```
public function get_results() 
{ 
    $libraries = array("", "JQuery", "MooTools", "YUI Library", "Glow"); 
    $table_rows = ''; 

    for ($i = 1; $i < 5; $i++) 
    {
         $this->db->select('COUNT(choice) choices_count')->from('js_libraries')->where('choice',$i);
         $result = $this->db->get();
         $table_rows .= "<tr><td>" . $libraries[$i] . " Got:</td><td><b>" . $result[0] . "</b> votes</td></tr>"; 
         
    } 
 }
```

I have executed the query on phpmyadmin and it shows result (a single integer) but I am unable to make this `CI_DB_mysql_result` object work. I have tried all `result(), result_array(), getResult()` functions but it says undefined functions for this kind of object. How can I get result from `CI_DB_mysql_result`?

Comment: Add `result_array` method to get result as array. `$result = $this->db->get()->result_array();`

Comment: I did this but it gave me `Array to string conversion` error on next line when getting results from $result[0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Thats because `result_array` returns 2D array which contains multiple rows from table. In this case you want only one row so you can use either of the following:

1. `row()` method which returns result as object.
   `$result = $this->db->get()->row();`
   Then `$result->choices_count` to get count value.
2. `row_array()` method which returns result as array.
   `$result = $this->db->get()->row_array();`
   Then `$result['choices_count']` to get count value.
3. `unbuffered_row()` method which returns result as object
   `$result = $this->db->get()->unbuffered_row();`
   Then `$result->choices_count` to get count value.
4. `unbuffered_row('array')` method which returns result as array.
   `$result = $this->db->get()->unbuffered_row('array');`
   Then `$result['choices_count']` to get count value.